# Standalone CUDA toolkit package (without installation)

Tags: cuda

In our C# environment we do not need the installation of the CUDA toolkit, since we have packaged everything into nuget packages so that the necessary components (like nvcc) and the necessary libraries (cuBlas, cuFFT) are coming from nuget.

The problem is that I need to build these packages by first installation the complete CUDA toolkit, meaning downloading it from the nvidia website, install it, create the necessary nuspec configs and then call nuget pack to create the packages.

Since there are continuous releases of CUDA we want to automate this so that the packages are downloaded automatically and the packages are created with scripts.

The problem is that I don't want to install the toolkit but just want to unpack the toolkit.
I haven't found a good way to do it. The only reference I could find was here, https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-toolkit-unpack-without-install/29615 but its for Ubuntu, and I need it for Windows.

I'm pretty sure that are some commandline switches for the installer but I haven't found out.

Any help on this?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. While reading through the docs (I did this already but didn't see it). you are able to extract the exe Installer file. I didn't even dare to try to unzip the exe but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

@talonmies brought this up. In the docs you can read

> Sometimes it may be desirable to extract or inspect the installable
> files directly, such as in enterprise deployment, or to browse the
> files before installation. The full installation package can be
> extracted using a decompression tool which supports the LZMA
> compression method, such as 7-zip or WinZip.
>
> Once extracted, the CUDA Toolkit files will be in the CUDAToolkit
> folder, and similarily for CUDA Visual Studio Integration. Within each
> directory is a .dll and .nvi file that can be ignored as they are not
> part of the installable files.

So you can indead unzip the installer (e.g. NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit_11.8_Machine_X64_exe_en-US.exe) which I downloaded with the command

```
winget download --id Nvidia.CUDA -d "D:\CUDA"
```

which isn't very well documented, but I found it here (https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/658) in the discussion that is was added without adding it obviously to some official docs (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/).

Since the installer is a self-extracting executable, you can use for example 7zip to extract. I currently haven't found a way to extract it per commandline but I'm still experimenting.